# Data propagation time (single link)

Tags: networking, tcp

this is not Home work!
I  preparing   my self to test in Networking :
i had this questen in the midterm test and i got **half the points** i cant figure it out

in this question i got  reciver-sender connection.

link data rate is R(b/s)

Packet size is S(b)

Window Size is W(pkts)

Link distance is  D(m)

medium propagation speed is  p(m/s)

i need to write the utilisation  Formula using those  Letters

this is what i wrote:

Tp-Propagation time is D/p ===>this got me a big X on test page

i wrote that frame transmition (Tt) time is  window size in bits (W*S)
divided by  link Data Rate i.e (W*S)/R

thats why  the formula is   U=Tt/(Tt+2*tp)==>((W*S)/R)/(((W*S)/R)+2*(D/p))
(again X)

i guess somthing is wrong with the **Propagation time calculation** .
all the slides refaring  to sliding window do not mention the utilisation 
in referande to distance and propagation delay

i would love some help with this.
thank you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how propagation time is supposed to be measured<sup>1</sup>, but the general formula is:

```
Propagation time = (Frame Serialization Time) + (Link Media Delay)
```

- `Link Media Delay = D/p`
- `Frame Serialization Time = S/R`

I don't see the relevance of TCP's sliding window in this question yet; sometimes professors include extra data to discern how well you understand the principles.

---

**END-NOTES**:

1. Does the professor measure propagation time at the bit-level or at the frame-level?  My answer assumes it is a frame-level calculation (measured from first bit transmitted until the last bit in the frame is received), so I include frame serialization time.

Comment: The Proffessor did not offered any Answers  on the test page :)
btw,got your comment about my Ratio thanks for that (i used more than 50% so thanks for the remark)

Comment: why to multiply it by 8 ?(the  packet is in bits )
the question   impliess that the   frames(packets in this question) sent in  window  so i need to multiply it  by  window size ?

Comment: @aristotaly, I did not realize packet size was bits, I edited.

Comment: i had this information missing. with your help
 I Got 90 on the test :)
thank you!